# Extract value from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this string:

```
O:37:"Ivory\GoogleMap\Service\Base\Distance":2:{s:43:"Ivory\GoogleMap\Service\Base\Distancetext";s:6:"572 km";s:44:"Ivory\GoogleMap\Service\Base\Distancevalue";i:572343;}
```

need to return only 572343 value.

Comment: 1) `unserialize()` it 2) Access the property

Comment: Looks like a clipped php serialized string. If you have the full string, use `unserialize` to get an array structure

Comment: Where did you get that string? There may be a better way to get that value.

Comment: var_dump return this:

object(Ivory\GoogleMap\Service\Base\Distance)#700 (2) { ["text":"Ivory\GoogleMap\Service\Base\Distance":private]=> string(6) "572 km" ["value":"Ivory\GoogleMap\Service\Base\Distance":private]=> int(572343) }

Comment: In which case, you DO NOT have a string. You have an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an array but a Google object that has been serialised. It expects you to have an object called `Distance` in the `Ivory\GoogleMap\Service\Base\` namespace.

I found a github repo that seems to handle that.

- https://github.com/yappabe/ivory-google-map

If that's not what you want you could try something a bit inelegant like reading backwards from the end of the string until you have all the digits.

```
str_replace(';}','',$string);
$output = '';
for ($i = -1; is_numeric(substr($string, $i,1)); $i--) {
    $output = substr($string, $i,1).$output;
}
echo $output;
```

or you could try `explode` using '";i:' as the token and grab the second element.

```
$pieces = explode('";i:', $string);
$number = str_replace(';}','',$pieces[1]);
echo $number;
```

Or you could do something a bit more stable with a regex (which as you might guess, I do not enjoy).

**Update:** from OP comments it seems that they are actually struggling with using a set of Google Ivory objects and not a string at all. That's a whole other question. However, if that were the string they needed to parse, my answer would help.

Comment: Solved to use 2 foreach loop as mentioned in the doc. Then get object propreties $element->getDistance():.... now i post another question because it generate Json problem